# SQL query works by itself but breaks with 'unknown column in on clause' in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

My select query with an inner joined subquery works when I run it alone, but results in the error `Unknown column 'cities.state' in 'on clause'` in the context of a stored procedure. What could cause a query that normally works to break inside a stored procedure? Why would this unknown column error be returned for `cities.state` and not `cities.name`? MySQL 5.7

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `geogen`(IN State CHAR(2), CityMin INT(5), CityMax INT(6))
BEGIN

#Create a temporary table to hold the final GeoArea product
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `geodb`.`geoareas`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `geodb`.`geoareas` LIKE `geodb`.`geoareatemplate`;

INSERT INTO `geodb`.`geoareas` (`geoarea`, `zip`, `state`)
# Zip code sets of cities/towns with a population between CityMin and CityMax are their own GeoAreas.
SELECT CONCAT(`uszipcode`.`name`, ' ', `uszipcode`.`state`) as 'geoarea', `uszipcode`.`zip`, `uszipcode`.`state`
FROM `geodb`.`uszipcode`
INNER JOIN
(SELECT `name`, `state`, SUM(`population`) AS 'Population'
FROM `geodb`.`uszipcode`
WHERE `uszipcode`.`state` = State
GROUP BY `name`
HAVING (SUM(`population`) >= CityMin AND SUM(`population`) <= CityMax)) as `cities`
ON `uszipcode`.`name` = `cities`.`name`
AND `uszipcode`.`state` = `cities`.`state`
ORDER BY `uszipcode`.`name`, `uszipcode`.`zip`;

SELECT * FROM geodb.geoareas;
END
```

When I run this query with

```
CALL geogen('TX', 35000, 70000);
```

I get the error

```
0   76  13:10:22    CALL geogen('TX', 35000, 70000) Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'cities.state' in 'on clause'  0.031 sec
```

However, when I run the query by itself, results are returned.

```
SELECT CONCAT(`uszipcode`.`name`, ' ', `uszipcode`.`state`) as 'geoarea', `uszipcode`.`zip`, `uszipcode`.`state`
FROM `geodb`.`uszipcode`
INNER JOIN
(SELECT `name`, `state`, SUM(`population`) AS 'Population'
FROM `geodb`.`uszipcode`
WHERE `uszipcode`.`state` = 'TX'
GROUP BY `name`
HAVING (SUM(`population`) >= 30000 AND SUM(`population`) <= 70000)) as `cities`
ON `uszipcode`.`name` = `cities`.`name`
AND `uszipcode`.`state` = `cities`.`state`
ORDER BY `uszipcode`.`name`, `uszipcode`.`zip`;
```

Result

```
LIMIT 0, 1000   121 row(s) returned 0.453 sec / 0.000 sec
```

Comment: How about wrapping the HAVING clause in parens?  e.g. `HAVING ((SUM ... AND \`uszipcode\`.\`state\` = \`cities\`.\`state\`)` ?

Comment: The HAVING clause is already paren wrapped (unless there's something I'm missing), but I added extra parens and it didn't change the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL was confused because the parameter/variable named `State` was similar to the column name `cities.state`. I believe this is a MySQL bug, because I used backticks and explicitly referenced the column by prefacing it with the table name, but please correct me if I am wrong and this is expected behavior. The results of the stored procedure matched the results of the standalone query when I updated the `State` parameter to `VarState` as shown below.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `geogen`(IN VarState CHAR(2), CityMin INT(5), CityMax INT(6))
BEGIN

#Create a temporary table to hold the final GeoArea product
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `geodb`.`geoareas`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `geodb`.`geoareas` LIKE `geodb`.`geoareatemplate`;

# Zip code sets of cities/towns with a population between CityMin and CityMax are their own GeoAreas.
INSERT INTO `geodb`.`geoareas` (`geoarea`, `zip`, `state`)
SELECT CONCAT(`uszipcode`.`name`, ' ', `uszipcode`.`state`) as 'geoarea', `uszipcode`.`zip`, `uszipcode`.`state`
FROM `geodb`.`uszipcode`
INNER JOIN
(SELECT `name`, `state`, SUM(`population`) AS 'Population'
FROM `geodb`.`uszipcode`
WHERE `uszipcode`.`state` = VarState
GROUP BY `name`
HAVING (SUM(`population`) >= CityMin AND SUM(`population`) <= CityMax)) AS `cities`
ON `uszipcode`.`name` = `cities`.`name`
AND `uszipcode`.`state` = `cities`.`state`
ORDER BY `uszipcode`.`name`, `uszipcode`.`zip`;

SELECT * FROM geodb.geoareas
ORDER BY `geoarea`, `zip`;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the `SELECT` in `()` as follows:

```
INSERT INTO `geodb`.`geoareas` (`geoarea`, `zip`, `state`)
(SELECT CONCAT(`uszipcode`.`name`, ' ', `uszipcode`.`state`) as 'geoarea', `uszipcode`.`zip`, `uszipcode`.`state`
FROM `geodb`.`uszipcode`
INNER JOIN
(SELECT `name`, `state`, SUM(`population`) AS 'Population'
FROM `geodb`.`uszipcode`
WHERE `uszipcode`.`state` = State
GROUP BY `name`, `state`
HAVING (SUM(`population`) >= CityMin AND SUM(`population`) <= CityMax)) as `cities`
ON `uszipcode`.`name` = `cities`.`name`
AND `uszipcode`.`state` = `cities`.`state`
ORDER BY `uszipcode`.`name`, `uszipcode`.`zip`);
```

Comment: Can you get the results when you run the `Select` statement without inserting it into the temp table from within the stored procedure?

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same results when modifying the stored procedure to return the results of a select statement. http://pastebin.com/x2mhJtGJ

Comment: So that means you are not able to access the temporary table `geodb.uszipcode` from the stored procedure. Can you create a real table instead and use that?

Comment: `geodb.uszipcode` is a real table. The only temporary table I'm creating is `geoareas` to put the results in. The subquery has a `cities` alias, and the issue appears to be that it can't access the `state` column of that alias, but has no issue with the `name` column of the same alias, which is weird.

Comment: Can you add `state` to `GROUP BY name, state` and then try again? GROUP BY `name`, `state`
HAVING (SUM(`population`) >= CityMin AND SUM(`population`) <= CityMax)) as `cities`
ON `uszipcode`.`name` = `cities`.`name`
AND `uszipcode`.`state` = `cities`.`state`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135625/discussion-between-tumen-t-and-gilbert).

Comment: Same error. I did take out that subquery aliased as `cities` and ran it by itself to make sure that it returned a state column.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `geogen`(IN State CHAR(2), CityMin INT(5), CityMax INT(6))
BEGIN

#temp cities
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `geodb`.`cities_temp`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `geodb`.`cities_temp`
SELECT `name`, `state`, SUM(`population`) AS 'Population'
FROM `geodb`.`uszipcode`
WHERE `uszipcode`.`state` = State
GROUP BY `name`
HAVING (SUM(`population`) >= CityMin AND SUM(`population`) <= CityMax) ;
#Create a temporary table to hold the final GeoArea product
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `geodb`.`geoareas`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `geodb`.`geoareas` LIKE `geodb`.`geoareatemplate`;

INSERT INTO `geodb`.`geoareas` (`geoarea`, `zip`, `state`)
# Zip code sets of cities/towns with a population between CityMin and CityMax are their own GeoAreas.
SELECT CONCAT(`uszipcode`.`name`, ' ', `uszipcode`.`state`) as 'geoarea', `uszipcode`.`zip`, `uszipcode`.`state`
FROM `geodb`.`uszipcode`
INNER JOIN
`geodb`.`cities_temp` as `cities`
ON `uszipcode`.`name` = `cities`.`name`
AND `uszipcode`.`state` = `cities`.`state`
ORDER BY `uszipcode`.`name`, `uszipcode`.`zip`;

SELECT * FROM geodb.geoareas;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This appears to be a suggestion to hack around the issue I'm having by inserting the results of my inner joined subquery into a temporary table and inner joining that instead of the subquery, which may work. Instead of creating a temporary table, I could also get rid of the AND part of the inner join constraint and add another subquery after the first FROM with a where constraint to select only records that match the State variable. But is there anything actually wrong with the syntax of my original stored procedure, or is this some kind of weird MySQL bug?

Comment: Exactly,Test adding delimiter.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. I do change the delimiter at the beginning and the end, it's just not in the code I posted.